# Is there some finished rendering event in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, rendering

I make my custom elements (inherited from Component). When I am trying to show 
 native alert from different places it sometimes hides and sometimes shows. I need to have an event to show alert exactly after rendering. Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you need to use states to check if the data is loaded

Comment: basically most close  is second argument of `setState` , like `setState(newStateObj, () => { /* here */ }) `

Comment: the componentDidMount() callback could be a good place on where to show it. Anyway you should add a bit of code at least to show the logic you're applying

Comment: @RajendranNadar But that doesnt tell if the component rendered or not